# Java and RabbitMQ - client server communication

Tags: java, rabbitmq, message-queue

Is it possible to establish communication between server/client in this way using RabbitMQ and AMQP:

1. Client send "command" to server
2. Server runs some logic (saving to database)
3. Server emits event (message) - "Data saved"
4. Client listen to that message and refresh presented data

***EDIT***

Is it possible to accomplish something like comunication betwen server and client in case of using nodejs with socket.io ?

Comunication must be non-blocking and async.

Or something like communication betwen client/server via Event Bus when using vert.x and Java. How my two or more Java clients can share data in real-time with some central server programmed in Java.

Comment: This sounds like a RPC or request/reply messaging pattern. It is supported by RabbitMQ through temporary destinations. For example check this tutorial: https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-six-java.html

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will have a look at that tutorial.

Comment: as @mjn said. Look into RPC. There are also tutorials around the web for doing RPC with socket.io and RabbitMQ